# Load HTTPS image URL IN ANDROID

Tags: android

I have been trying to load HTTPS image url ,How to load **HTTPS image URL** in android from existing personal secured server?

Answer (score 3):

Place your URL in place of IMAGE_URL then Glide will do rest of work

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(IMAGE_URL)
    .into(imageView);
```

Dependency if it's missing in build.gradle

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin use Coil

In your app level gradle file add following line.

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.1.0")
```

Then to load an image

```
imageView.load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg")
```