# Does anyone know how to get gif images working in android app?

Tags: java, android, image, animated-gif

I am developing social media app in which I already coded the logic to take image from my phone gallery but when I retrieve gif image from gallery it doesn't show me any animation of that gif image, it just shows the still image and I have post feature also but there also it doesn't show me animation of gif image, so if anyone know how to get the gif image working on android app then please help me.

The logic to retrieve image from gallery is:

this is a onClick function when i click on camera icon it take me back to gallery.

```
Photo.launch("image/*");
```

before this i created the global variable for photo and then i stored the image in the firebase database using registerForActivityResult

I want to know how to get the gif image animation working after I retrieve them from gallery.

Comment: Use Glide as your image loader, as [Glide supports GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31082330/115145). Or, use [a dedicated GIF library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/193?sort=created).

Comment: Load gif using `coil` https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/gifs/

Comment: @Ammar Abdullah where should i add that code for image loader in my project in which file ?

Comment: @ramshinde check it out . It for loading images using `Glide` https://stackoverflow.com/a/72543476/15218726

Comment: Just replace `.load(IMAGE_URL)` with `.load(R.drawable.your_gif)`

Comment: @Ammar Abdullah, Thank you Ammar but I am trying to fetch gifs from my emulators gallery just like the normal images and when I fetch any gif image from gallery it does not show me any animation just frozen image of that gif so if you can help me with that then that would be amazing.

Comment: pass that gif uri from `onActivityResult` to `.load(uri)` then Glide will play gif for you